# Assigning value of User Defined Class (UDC) to textbox

Tags: vb.net

Im learning about UDC in vb.net and trying to get a very simple program to display the value of a UDC in a textbox my code follows below:

```
Structure carDriverInfo
        Dim carMake As String
        Dim driverName As String
End Structure

 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim car As carDriverInfo
        Dim driver As carDriverInfo

        car.carMake = "Ford Fiesta"
        driver.driverName = "J Hudgsons"

        TextBox1.Text = car
        TextBox2.Text = driver
    End Sub
```

The problem is the compiler gives me the error that CarDriverInfo cannot get converted to string...
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can only assign a string to the Text property of the TextBox. So you could assign car.CarMake or car.DriverName, but not the car itsellf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler doesn't know what variable to show.  You can choose one value that will represent string output of your structure by adding following to your structure

```
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return carName
    End Function
```

But if you want to get different values from your structure you need to define your variables as properties and use those properties as you see fit like

```
car.carName
```

Comment: Thanks for you effort

Comment: @Nick I have removed the code snippet. Code snippets work (for now) only for JavaScript examples. Have a look at this [SE blog article](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).